# Querying dbset using collection of IDs - how to use .Any()?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dbset

I have this query:

```
var qClaims = from c in CasaLatinaEntities.tblClaims
              where c.PersonID == PersonID
              select c;

var qClaimStatus = CasaLatinaEntities.lnktblClaimStatusClaims
                  .Where(cs => cs.ClaimID == qClaims
                  .Any(c => c.ClaimID));
```

The second query doesn't work but what I am trying to do is get all data from lnktblClaimStatusClaims that matches the IDs in qClaims. ClaimID is PK in qClaims and FK in lnktblClaimStatusClaims.

Does anyone know a good way of writing this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly, you need to reorder the query a bit, as LINQ doesn't have SQL-like syntax.

```
var qClaimStatus = CasaLatinaEntities.lnktblClaimStatusClaims
                  .Where(cs => qClaims.Any(c => c.ClaimID == cs.ClaimID));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could use my lambda expression in that way. My query has problems because I am trying to compare a single value with a collection of values. But writing cs => qClaims.Any means I am comparing values of same type. I learn't something new today :)